Access destructured value inside function body in vue
In the docs for vue's v-model modifiers, they give this example and there is a playground link as well.
<script setup>
const [model, modifiers] = defineModel({
  set(value) {
    if (modifiers.capitalize) {
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
    }
    return value
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="model" />
</template>

This code can be edited so that the modifiers variable is now foo. What kind of pattern is this and how is this achievable (with pseudocode) since the value of const [model, foo] = ... is in a different scope than foo.capitalize?
<script setup>
const [model, foo] = defineModel({
//            ^^^
  set(value) {
    if (foo.capitalize) {
//      ^^^
      return value.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + value.slice(1)
    }
    return value
  }
})
</script>

<template>
  <input type="text" v-model="model" />
</template>


modifiers (and foo) are just variable names - you can call them what you want - not sure what you mean by a different scope ... you haven't changed the scope of anything by simply changing a variable name from something meaningful to something generic

Inside of set there is this bit foo.capitalize, and it's linked with const [foo] = .... If you wrote const [bar] = ... then in set you could use bar.capitalize. In a normal js function you can't access the destructured values like this.

you could do const [foo, bar] = defineModel({ set(bat) { .... and as long as you use foo instead of model, bar instead of modifiers and bat instead of value, the code is functionally identical

Oh, I see your confusion ... const [a, b] = ... de-structures an array, the values are assigned by ordinal position within the array ... you're confusing this with const {a, b} = .... - did you not notice in the actual documentation, they use const [modelValue, modelModifiers] = defineModel({ not const [model, modifiers] = defineModel({

try const [a, b] = [1, 2] ... see how a and b can be absolutely any valid variable name?

I think the confusion is this: you maybe think that foo is read (with foo.capitalize) at a time that foo must still be assigned with [model, foo] =, but that is a misunderstanding. The set method is not yet called. It is only defined. The call of set will happen later, long after the assignment  to [model, foo] already happened. And as to scope: surely the set method has access to variables that have been defined outside its function scope. This is a core principle in JS.

The question is how defineModel might look internally with pseudocode. Usually you can't access a destructured value inside a function's body.

what does the name you assign to the variable have to do with it?

@trincot I think that's it, you are right.

@dbzx10299 As you correctly noted, there would be an error if foo were accessed before it's created. That this works proves that it's not accessed. FWIW, defineModel creates a writable computed, and set is called only when model.value is assigned.

As stated in comments, the fact that you can change the variable name and achieve the same results, is expected: there is nothing special to the name model -- it is just a name.
What can be confusing is that the set method reads from a variable that is only defined and assigned a value in the same expression that set method occurs in.
But realise that this set method is not yet called when defineModel is called. The foo (or model) variable will be initialised by this overall expression, but the set method is not called by this expression. This whole expression has already been evaluated and assigned to foo before the set method is ever called.
NB: It would have been a problem if the defineModel function would itself call the set method of the given object. If that were the case, foo would be undefined, and an error would be triggered when evaluating foo.capitalize.
As to the parsing of this code: the foo variable is declared, and its name is known for the set function, and can be parsed without issue.
Example
This principle is not specific for Vue. It is how things work in plain JavaScript.
Here is a simple JavaScript example, where foo is assigned without destructuring (which was an irrelevant aspect), and set is called explicitly with some format function that is made available to foo:


function create(obj) {
    console.log("executing: create()");
    return {
        capitalize: true,
        format(value) { return obj.set(value); }
    };
}

const foo = create({
    set(value) {
        console.log("executing: set()");
        if (foo.capitalize) value = value.toUpperCase();
        return value;
    }
});
console.log("foo was assigned");

// Only now `set` will be called
const value = foo.format("hello world");
console.log(value);



So, notice the order of the output that this snippet generates.

This is starting to make sense defineModel is called immediately and the set method is called later. For the sake of completeness, could you create a simplified bare bones pseudocode example just to help visualize?

Added a runnable snippet (unrelated to Vue), which illustrates the order of execution.

This usage of defineModel macro roughly translates to:
export default {
  props: {
    modelValue: null,
    modelModifiers: { default: () => ({}) }
  },
  emits: ['update:modelValue'],
  setup(props, { emit }) {
    const model = computed({
      get() {
        return props.modelValue;
      },
      set(value) {
        if (modifiers.value.capitalize) {
        ...
        emit('update:modelValue', value);
      }
    );
    const modifiers = computed(() => props.modelModifiers);
    ...

defineModel returns an array of 2 elements (tuple) that can be destructured, so model and modifiers variable names are arbitrary.
modifiers is accessed inside a computed at the time when model.value is changed, so this can't cause modifiers is not defined error.
